# Why does Jenkins Credentials show "This ID is already in use"

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-plugins

I am doing a fresh install of Jenkins on an EC2 Ubuntu AMI. I install the default set of plugins (which includes the Credentials plugin). After logging in, I go to the Credentials link, select the default Global domain, and add a new credential. After I add a username with password credential (leaving the ID blank), I am able to add it. But then when I click on Update, I see "This ID is already in use" message under the ID field. I have tried this with Jenkins 2.23, 2.21, and 2.18 and I keep seeing the same message. Anyone know why this could be happening? [Credentials Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaHa6.png)

Comment: Maybe you are logged in in with the admin credentials....and when you try to update the admin user it doesn't let you do that because is already in use....you need to update the admin account login in with another user

Comment: Doesn't affect anything. The message I get saying that the ID is already in use is actually related to the Credentials that Jenkins uses to connect to other services such as Github; not the user I use to log into Jenkins. Regardless of that, I created another login user and tried to access (and create) credentials using a different user and got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem went away once I changed the version of one of the plugins. The Credentials Plugin version 2.1.5 was showing this problem. Once I changed the version of that particular plugin from 2.1.5 to 2.1.4, the problem went away and I haven't seen it since.

Answer (score 0):

Should be fixed with (not released yet) `v2.1.6`: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38861

**EDIT**: New version `v2.1.6` was released and fixes the problem for me.